# ImportError: No module named streams

Tags: python, django

I am setting up django(1.6) project locally. I have installed all modules including activity-stream but When I try to run server "python manage.py runserver 8081", i am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 284, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 310, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 34, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 196, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 78, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 99, in load_app
    models = import_module('%s.models' % app_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/actstream/models.py", line 46, in <module>
    class Action(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/actstream/models.py", line 99, in Action
    objects = actstream_settings.get_action_manager()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/actstream/settings.py", line 24, in get_action_manager
    return getattr(__import__(j(a[:-1]), {}, {}, [a[-1]]), a[-1])()
ImportError: No module named streams
```

Comment: Do you have `setuptools` installed what happens when you do a quick `pip freeze | grep -i stream`?

Comment: Can you verify you have this package installed in the system wide python's `site-packages` or that you have sourced the correct `virtualenv`? Do you have any luck if you `pip uninstall django-activity-stream && pip install django-activity-stream`.

Comment: yes package is installed system wide. I am getting same error after uninstalling and installing it.

Comment: How did you verify the installation?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you haven't streams.py file in your django project where you have to describe your SomeActionManager which inherited from actstream.ActionManager. If you described it in project settings but don't create streams.py, acstream raise ImportError, if you not describe - acstream load default module. Here settings from [example_project](https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream/blob/master/example_project/settings.py), look in ACTSTREAM_SETTINGS section.